# Which is the proper way to use this phrase?

Tags: phrases

Example sentences with phrase in bold:

> It's really quite enthralling **I might add**.
>
> It's really quite enthralling **might I add**.
>
> It's really quite enthralling **might I add you**.

I've heard all three used, but which is correct?

Comment: Do you mean *his being added is enthralling you?*

Comment: Definitely not the last one. Consider 'might I add that it's really quite enthralling'

Answer (score 1):

I have heard both "I might add", and "might I add". Strangely, I've only heard the latter when the speaker is contradicting, or expressing indignation about, what they have just heard. In contrast I've heard "I might add" being used in the same way that one might see "moreover", or "furthermore" being used in a piece of writing.

Comment: I believe the construction of moving the verb to the front of a sentence ( both are restatements of "I might add it's really quite enthralling") turns it into a question, in this case a question you are answering by going right ahead and adding your point.

Answer (score 1):

According to me, the first one is the corrent one

> It's really quite enthralling **I might add**.